# Every time I start Mythbuntu the xfce menu shows, I have to restart MythTV to get it full screen

Tags: xfce, mythbuntu, mythtv

I'm running an up-to-date (I did an apt-get upgrade last night) Mythbuntu install (myth 0.26) as a combined backend/frontend.

Every night I shut down the machine and turn it back on in the morning. I have no tuners only get-iplayer, miro-bridge and some HLS tuners (which don't seem to work very well, but that's another story) so there's no need for me to leave it on overnight unnecessarily.

Every morning when it starts up the MythTV frontend is displayed underneath the XFCE menu/panel. I can ssh and kill mythfrontend for it to restart, I can go Setup -> Looks and just next my way through and then it will reload or I can delete a video (movies rather than recording) and press rescan and it will crash and reload (why does it crash?). All of those things fix it.

Also I occasionally get the screensaver coming on when it shouldn't, the same things fix that too.

This seems to have happened since I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, so is there something wrong with the startup of mythfrontend? Has it changed slightly?

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you can script this:
DISPLAY=:0 wmctrl -r "MythTV Frontend" -b add,fullscreen

that will overrride the fullscreen behavior.  Still not understood what the root cause is (https://bugs.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/+bug/1282868)